# Can we get our first custom close reason/migration path set up?

Tags: discussion, homebrew, migration, close-reasons

We've had a half dozen questions that really clearly belong on Homebrew.se already.

It's in our best interest to nip these in the bud sooner than later, so can we set up the migration path a bit more quickly than might be normal for a beta? Or at least a custom close reason that mentions Homebrew.SE?

Answer (score 2):

Custom close reason should come soon, though maybe not until after we get our pro-tem mods (about 2 weeks into public beta), though we may be able to campaign to get the community team to add one about homebrew.

However, migration paths will not come until we have graduated which is too far in the future for us to be thinking about right now.

Comment: Don't forget that migrating towards beta sites is actually discouraged by SE

Comment: @LucasKauffman only for *early* betas.